# Comparing file size of downloaded file with remote file on ftp server

Tags: java, unix, ftp, sftp, ftp-client

I am using FTPClient to download files from remote FTP Server.

After downloading, I would like to compare the size of local file and remote file if they are same.

Once the file is downloaded, the size of downloaded file is different from the one in remote server.

Below is the code snippet

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if( getFTPFileType()!=null ){
                            // set as binary  
            ftpClient.setFileType(getFTPFileType(), getFTPFileType());
            ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(getFTPFileType());
        }
        if( getLog().isDebugEnabled()){
            getLog().debug("FTP File Type "+getFTPFileType());
        }
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile.getName(), output);
```

If I download in windows environment, it works fine. But if I download in AIX server, there is difference between file sizes. I compared the downloaded files, the content is same.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the number of bytes difference in size ~= the number of lines in the file, it is due to the removal of windows carriage control characters: `\r` or `^M` as they appear in vi.

And the content is not the same in the sense that checksums would fail.

Edit:

inside ftp: dir filename will return something like this

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group        1224 Mar  4 20:22 twrite.c
```

I have no good idea on how to get your java class to send that command. Check your documentation.  When you can get `dir` working, you can tokenize the string you get back, the fifth field is the number of bytes on the remote side.

Example using unix shell (java will let you run UNIX scripts), after fileA has been dowloaded from remote to local:

```
local_size=$(ls -l fileA | awk '{print $5}')
/usr/bin/ftp -n  <<EOF > ftp.log
open remote_nodename
user username password
cd /directory/to/files
dir fileA
bye
END
remote_size=$(grep 'fileA' ftp.log | awk '{print $5}')
[ $remote_size -eq $local_size ] && echo 'OK' || echo 'NOTOK'
```

If you can emulate this with java classes okay, otherwise you need to use something like this which shows the use of runtime exec():

```
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8
```

Again, to vbe clear ftp does NOT run shell scripts on the remote side.  ssh does.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Whats the way around for this problem. I thought of comparing the hash of the local file and remote file, but I can't do the hash for the FTPFile, so I am stuck there as well. I would really like to check some way that local file has been downloaded properly either by comparing size of hash or something else.

Comment: See example added to the answer